# FMDatabase database locked

Tags: objective-c, fmdb

So, I created an app that stores some data. However, every time, after I've called the delete function I wrote, and then call a different function, I get an error saying `database locked`.

This is the function:

```
+ (void)deleteRestaurants:(NSString *)number {
    FMDatabase *database = [sDatabase openUp];

    [database open];

    FMResultSet *rs = [database executeQuery:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM restaurants WHERE id='%@'", number]];
    if ([rs next]) {
        NSString *cloudKit = [rs stringForColumn:@"CloudKit"];

        NSLog(@"CloudKit is %@", cloudKit);

        CKRecordID *recordID = [[CKRecordID alloc] initWithRecordName:cloudKit];

        NSLog(@"recordID is %@", recordID);

        [[CKContainer defaultContainer].privateCloudDatabase deleteRecordWithID:recordID completionHandler:^(CKRecordID *recordID, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
        }];
    }

    NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"delete from restaurants where id='%@'", number];
    [database executeUpdate:query];
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Or how can I solve/prevent this?

Comment: Try `[rs close]` before executing the delete statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rob mayor is right. You need [rs close]. Would look like this:

```
FMResultSet *rs = [database executeQuery:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM restaurants WHERE id='%@'", number]];
if ([rs next]) {
    NSString *cloudKit = [rs stringForColumn:@"CloudKit"];

    NSLog(@"CloudKit is %@", cloudKit);

    CKRecordID *recordID = [[CKRecordID alloc] initWithRecordName:cloudKit];

    NSLog(@"recordID is %@", recordID);

    [[CKContainer defaultContainer].privateCloudDatabase deleteRecordWithID:recordID completionHandler:^(CKRecordID *recordID, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }];
}
[rs close];
```

Answer (score 1):

user4992124 I will give you the sample code for deleting the data.Please customize the code regarding to your coding.

```
- (IBAction)actionDelete:(id)sender
{
   NSArray *dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
   NSString *docDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
   NSString *databasePath = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourDBName.sqlite"];

  FMDatabase *database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:databasePath];

  [database open];

  [database executeUpdate:@"delete from phone where id = ?",number];

  UIAlertView *alert =[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Sample SQLite" message:@"Deleted Successfully" delegate:Nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"otherButtonTitles: nil];
  [alert show];

  [database close];

}
```